# PHP and Javascript Longpolling

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, streaming

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I am trying to realize "Live Logging" in one of my web applications by opening an async connection to my php backend which should constantly send out log data via echo / print statements.

I already tried the example "Streaming with Ajax" from this page https://www.sitepoint.com/php-streaming-output-buffering-explained/ but it just wont work.

HTML + JS

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Ajax Streaming Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <center><a href="#" id="test">Test Ajax Streaming</a></center>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById('test').onclick = function() {
         xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open("GET", "response.php", true);
         xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
           alert(e.currentTarget.responseText);
         }
         xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
             console.log("Complete = " + xhr.responseText);
           }
         }
         xhr.send();
       };
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

PHP File (Just took it as is was displayed on the site)

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++): ?>
  <?php sleep(1); ?>
  Count = <?php echo "$i\n"; ?>
  <?php ob_flush(); flush(); ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

I disabled **output_buffering** and also enabled **ob_implicit_flush**.

The expected result is that after your pressed the "Test Ajax Streaming" button, an alert pops up showing "Count = 1", followed by another alert showing "Count = 1, Count = 2" etc...

In my case I just get one alert showing the complete content of the for loop.

Since the article is from 2014 I imagine PHP and Apache changed a lot since then so is Streaming with PHP like this still possible ?

I am using the following version

PHP Version: PHP 7.1.12

Apache Version: Apache/2.4.29 (Fedora)

Comment: Perhaps it's worth you looking into WebSockets.

Comment: @Jon Stirling WebSockets are sadly not an option because I want to integrate it into a WordPress plugin.

Comment: Not really sure why that stops it being an option... but okay.

Comment: Your code works on my xampp setup: Apache/2.4.10, PHP/5.6.3, so I guess it's a configuration issue.